# Template Development Workflow with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, templates, workflow, freemarker

I'm working on a Spring WebMVC project that generates HTML output by using FreeMarker templates. A site controller returns a view name and a data model which is then fed into the view template.

Sample controller method (in `/src/main/java/com/mycompany/controller.java`):

```
@RequestMapping("/example")
public ModelAndView handleRequest() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("my_tempate");
    mv.addObject("my_data", "my_value");
    return mv;
}
```

Sample template for this (which resides in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/my_template.ftl`):

```
<title>Sample Template</title>
<p>I'm a sample template, I output: ${my_data}</p>
```

I package a `.war` file and deploy it to tomcat with `mvn tomcat7:redeploy`. This process takes about 4-5 seconds for my very small code base. For changes to the java code I'm fine with this compilation time. However for developing HTML templates it is a very unsatisfying workflow having to redeploy my `.war` file with every change.

Is it possible to set up Spring to not read template files from the `.war` file package but rather from the local file system while in development mode? So I could point in the source to an absolute path like `/home/user/my_project/my_template.ftl` that is parsed on every site request.

Comment: Can't you just deploy the app exploded? Then the templates are just plain files, not something inside an archive.

Comment: Turns out, my deployment process automatically deploys an exploded war. Exactly what I was looking for. If you want to formulate an answer I will accept it.